# How to create my own attributes on $stateProvider.state

Tags: angularjs

I did authorization with $cookies. Everything is work.

```
$http.post("/api/account/login", $scope.userData)
        .then(function onSuccess(response) {
            $cookies.put('token', response.data.access_token);
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token;

        }).catch(function onError(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
```

I have return from backend and put all data to token and header. Its work and header too.

In my main module I want implement next attributes

```
 $stateProvider


         .state('home', {
             url: '/',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/home.html',
             controller: 'HomeController',
             authenticate: false,   //-this
         })

         .state('education', {
             url: '/education',
             templateUrl: 'app/pages/education.html',
             controller: 'EducationController',
             authenticate: false,   //-this


         })
```

I tried it to do by this example
https://www.octobot.io/blog/2016-11-25-angularjs-ui-router-per-view-authorization/
 but no result. 
What must I do after "function onSuccess(response)" on login controller that my attributes "authenticate: false/true" will work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [embed.plnkr.co](http://embed.plnkr.co/TWiDY3/preview), its use full for this issue.